# How to resolve HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ads.google.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=3600) error?

Tags: python, google-ad-manager, request-timed-out

I have been using a python script to download a report from google AdManager using a saved query. However, when I try to run the script to download the report I face the timeout error. I tried to find a solution for it but haven't been able to resolve it yet.

Following is the specific code to download the report from AdManager:

```
# Download report data.
print("Report download starting...")
time.sleep(0.5)
report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(report_job_id, export_format, report_file)
report_file.close()

# Display results.
print('Report job with id "%s" downloaded to:\n%s' % (report_job_id, report_file.name))
```

The official link to download a report is here: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reporting#python This link will provide elaborate information about Reporting AdManager API. After opening the link please go to the **Downloading the Report** section to investigate the code.

Following is the error that I'm facing.

> Image 1 as shown below

[image]

> Image 2 as shown below

[image]

**Note:** I have gone through the other similar posts, however, those are not relevant for my case.

Comment: did you manage to fix this? maybe there is a timeout param that can be configured?